# How to keep position of multiple ImageView's on a large image on different display sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, position, imageview, relationship

I am trying to make an app that displays the guitar chords, selected in a spinner.

Therefore I made a large image of the guitar neck and a couple of small dot-images, positioned on the frets of the neck. To show different chords, I just set the right dots visible and the other ones invisible. So far so good.

My problem now is how to keep the dots on the right position of the large `ImageView` when using another device with different resolution.

Here you can see the problem:

[image]

Here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:contentDescription="back"
        android:text="@string/Lagerfeuer" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/back"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back"
        android:background="@drawable/back2"
        android:contentDescription="back2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/Lagerfeuer"
        android:textColor="#b4b4b4"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/chordSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/griffbrett"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/chordSpinner"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/griffbrett" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c11"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/griffbrett"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c21"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c11"
        android:layout_below="@id/c11"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c31"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c11"
        android:layout_below="@id/c21"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c41"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c11"
        android:layout_below="@id/c31"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c51"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c11"
        android:layout_below="@id/c41"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c61"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c11"
        android:layout_below="@id/c51"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c12"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/c11"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/c11"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c22"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c12"
        android:layout_below="@id/c11"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c32"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c12"
        android:layout_below="@id/c21"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c42"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c12"
        android:layout_below="@id/c31"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c52"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c12"
        android:layout_below="@id/c41"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c62"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c12"
        android:layout_below="@id/c51"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c13"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/c11"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/c12"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c23"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c13"
        android:layout_below="@id/c11"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c33"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c13"
        android:layout_below="@id/c21"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c43"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c13"
        android:layout_below="@id/c31"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c53"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c13"
        android:layout_below="@id/c41"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c63"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c13"
        android:layout_below="@id/c51"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c14"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/c11"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/c13"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c24"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c14"
        android:layout_below="@id/c11"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c34"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c14"
        android:layout_below="@id/c21"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c44"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c14"
        android:layout_below="@id/c31"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c54"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c14"
        android:layout_below="@id/c41"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c64"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c14"
        android:layout_below="@id/c51"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c15"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/c11"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/c14"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c25"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c15"
        android:layout_below="@id/c11"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c35"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c15"
        android:layout_below="@id/c21"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c45"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c15"
        android:layout_below="@id/c31"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c55"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c15"
        android:layout_below="@id/c41"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/c65"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/c15"
        android:layout_below="@id/c51"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s1"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/c11"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s2"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/c11"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s3"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/c21"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s4"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/c31"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s5"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/c41"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s6"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/c51"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know, this was probably not the best solution of doing such a layout, and I don't expect you to go through this long XML file entirely, but maybe anyone could give me an advise how to solve this easier.

Thank you in forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml layout to do this is a lot of work. 
My opinion is that you create some custom view, and implement the onMeasure() and onDraw method. You can set the view height in onMeasure(), and draw those dots in the onDraw() method. 
There is a good tutorial of implementing your own custom view
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

If you really want to do this in an xml layout, there is a way :
You can get the screen's height and width by

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

Set the LayoutParams of each imageView in your layout accordingly by calculating accurately using screen's width and height.